# How to always display google recaptcha in english language?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

I am using latest google recaptcha in my ASP.Net MVC project. By default, it takes up the language set in the browser.

However, I want it to be displayed always in english.

Here is what I have tried so far:

My Script for onload:

```
 var onloadCallback = function () {
        // Renders the HTML element with id 'example1' as a reCAPTCHA widget.
        // The id of the reCAPTCHA widget is assigned to 'widgetId1'.

        //widgetId1 = grecaptcha.render(document.getElementById('g-recaptcha'), {
        //    'sitekey': '6Lc2Zf8SAAAAAOC9_6L7k5mCnxGao7vCv5_1KxrL'
        //});
        grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha', {
            'sitekey': '6LdRfv8SAAAAAOagkckxW72cHAQKrvNGLasbU6G2',
            'callback': verifyCallback,
            'theme': 'dark',
            'lang': 'en'
        });
    };
```

Can we force recaptcha to be always displayed in a certain language?

Answer (score 3):

I finally got the answer.

In the link to include the Google recaptcha, you can pass your language in form of query string:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=fr&onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

Comment: It really works. I can't understand why people vote down to useful answers.